# Regular expression gets values even though the lookbehind should be triggered

Tags: python, regex

I have a regular expression that is used mainly to find measurements (either amps, watts, or volts) in strings. The strings are at most 80 characters long. Here is the regex I am using:

```
(?<![a-zA-Z])[\-\s\(,\n=]?([0-9?\.?]+\-?)\s?(amps|volts|watts|volt|amp|watt|a|v|w){1}(?![a-zA-Z]+)
```

The reason I am so specific in the specification of the units is that when I try putting it into the re module of python, it would mess up if I was to use something like `watt(s)?`. It would return random "s" characters it found in the string. Also, the reason I use so many capture groups is that when I use `re.findall()` it returns the capture groups, so I can easily process the data. I am also using the case-insensitive flag.

This is an example of the issue I am having is shown in the table below:

```
| String     | Result   |
|------------|----------|
| E2A        | 2 Amps   |
| ESQ45A     | 5 Amps   |
| JW795A     | 795 Amps |
```

It triggers on those, even though the lookbehind should see that there is a letter before it. Is there a way to have the regex stop looking because the lookbehind was triggered? I cannot use the `^` character because these strings are rarely at the beginning of the string

Here is the [regex101 link with a few more examples](https://regex101.com/r/YU36sX/2). T

These shouldn't match:

```
ESQ45A
JW795A
SO15A
SQ18W
SQQ10W
AK10V
```

These should match:

```
XYZ 5 amps
1 V
1123 w
5 Volt
1234 amp
```

Comment: What's `[0-9?\.?]` supposed to mean?

Comment: @Tomalak All numbers including ones with a decimal place

Comment: Change the lookbehind to `(?<![a-zA-Z\d])`, otherwise all it does is skip the first digit of the number.

Comment: You don't realize that this matches question marks. There are no "optionals" in a character class. You mean `\d+(\.\d+)?`.

Comment: use http://regexr.com (or smth alike) to explain your regex. `[0-9?\.?]` means any of those letters literally (expand ranges 0-9 to 0123456789)

Comment: Check https://regex101.com/r/kYofyw/1. Or https://regex101.com/r/kYofyw/2. If you posted exact requirements, what contexts you want to match the measurements in, it would be easier to help you.

Comment: `[\-\s\(,\n=]` also looks dubious.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I added the regex 101 link to the post, also what do you mean by exact requirements?

Comment: @ekhumoro that is mainly for if there is a space, or a - in front of the measurement which sometimes there is.

Comment: @Gorlan That link does not help: are those inputs to be matched or not? What is the expected result?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew for those, the results should be nothing.

Comment: Then what should it match? Have you checked my regexps?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew ahh ok. I updated the link to have what it should match.

Comment: So, [does my regex work for you?](https://regex101.com/r/vHRG5J/1) You are just showing some examples, but still provide no pattern requirements.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I really don't understand what your asking. The pattern should find both the number and the unit in a measurement. Both in individual capture groups.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew looking over your regex, it does work for me! would the way I handle for other characters other than a space be by replacing `\s*` with `[\s\(\-]*`?

Comment: What "way"? You did not explain any way in your question. What format of numbers do you expect to match? What (and how many) characters do you expect that divide the number from the measurement unit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Judging by the examples, you need to use

```
\b(\d*\.?\d+)\s*(a(?:mps?)?|v(?:olts?)?|w(?:atts?)?)\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vHRG5J/1).

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(\d*\.?\d+)` - Group 1: an int- or float-like number
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespace chars
- `(a(?:mps?)?|v(?:olts?)?|w(?:atts?)?)` - Group 2: `a`, `v`, `w`, `amp`, `amps`, `volt`, `volts`, `watt` or `watts`
- `\b` - a word boundary.

Note that `\d*\.?\d+` matches `0.12`, `.12` and `112` values, you may use `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` to avoid matching `.12`-like values.

If you have 1 or more whitespace between the number and the measurement unit, replace `\s*` with `\s+`. You may add more chars here by using a character class like `[\s=-]` (e.g. adding a `=` and `-`). Feel free to customize futher.